# Eclipse and Spring Tool Suit (STS) hangs all the time in ubuntu mate

Tags: java, eclipse, mate, cpufreq

I find this problem with many of the linux and eclipse users who are facing this problem. When I use any other application like chrome, vlc or gimp, ubuntu mate 15.10 works fine. But when I run eclipse, it hangs all the time. Moreover STS just closes unexpectedly time to time.

Is this the problem with ubuntu or eclipse? Please give me some suggestions to solve this problem.

Thank you